# SQL Server - Function to parse field data to separate columns

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2019

**I have looked at ~8 threads similar to this, but none that address my exact need (there is a lack of delimiter consistency in the column in question here), so please don't mark as possible duplicate without fully reading and understanding what I'm asking.**

Azure SQL Server 2019:

I've inherited a table called dbo.Table that has millions of records that look like this:

```
Id   Body
1    Status: Completed
     Successful actions count: 106
     Page load count: 105

2    Status: Failed
     Successful actions count: 91
     Page load count: 90

3    Status: Completed
     Successful actions count: 44
     Page load count: 32
```

I'm aware (and annoyed at the fact) that this structure is less than optimal.  I need to fix it and would appreciate any advice toward the right direction:

I have added three columns to the table: `Status`, `Successful_Actions_Count`, and `Page_Load_Count`.

What would be the best method for parsing the data from the `Body` column to the three new columns, both for the existing data, and future inserts?

I am not looking for someone to write a Stored Procedure for me.  Rather something along the lines of what SQL Server functions are available to me that would facilitate this, and is it best to accomplish this via Stored Procedure for existing, and Trigger for future?

I was looking at `STRING_SPLIT`, but that appears to be geared toward comma-separated strings (or some other delimiter). The challenge here to me with my limited SQL skills is that there is no consistent delimiter to use - space obviously won't work.  Any thoughts from the SQL experts out there would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** 
I have used @Zhorov solution below to *display* results the way we need to see them, but this isn't working inside a Trigger such that we can actually write the results to the record as it comes in.

Here is the Trigger creation statement - I'm testing it with just one of the columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[BodyParseTrigger] on [dbo].[MailArchive]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO dbo.MailArchive (
 Status
)
SELECT 
j.*
FROM INSERTED
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status'
     ) j
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

The create command completes successfully.  But anytime an `INSERT` operation on the table happens, I get an error message that prevents the `INSERT` entirely.  The message is:

> JSON text is not properly formatted.  Unexpected character "'" is
>   found at position 10.

This is the first issue to overcome with the Trigger - once I figure that out, I will also need to understand how to put multiple of these`OPENJSON` statements in to cover all 3 of the columns.  Writing it as in @Zhorov answer makes it as only one item to be inserted as a value, where the Trigger expects 3 items.

Comment: Actually, you do have consistent delimiter... char(13)

Comment: A table named `dbo.Table` has records with delimited data inside them? I'm SHOCKED. Are there dates stored as varchar as well with varying formats? `STRING_SPLIT()` is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Note that T-SQL is a poor language to do string manipulation in, even with the functions added in 2016+; it pays to keep open the option of manipulating the data through client code, as it has much more freedom in parsing, and also more flexibility for handling errors. If redirecting the table inserts to another system for processing is not an option, this can be client code in the database itself (CLR functions/procedures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer:**

Another possible approach is JSON transformation (as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned in the comments). You need to transform `Body` data into a valid JSON object and parse this object with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int,
   Body varchar(max) 
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (Id, Body)
VALUES
   (1, 'Status: Completed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Successful actions count: 106' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Page load count: 105'),
   (2, 'Status: Failed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Successful actions count: 91' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Page load count: 90'),
   (3, 'Status: Completed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Successful actions count: 40' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Page load count: 44')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
   Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
   Page_Load_Count int '$."Page load count"'
) j
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Status      Successful_Actions_Count    Page_Load_Count
-------------------------------------------------------
Completed   106                         105
Failed      91                          90
Completed   40                          44
```

If you have `NULL` values in the `Body` column, you may try with something like this:

```
SELECT d.Id, j.*
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (
   CASE 
      WHEN d.Body IS NULL THEN '{}'
      ELSE CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')
   END   
) WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
   Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
   Page_Load_Count int '$."Page load count"'
) j
```

If the data in the `Body` column ends with new line, you'll need to add an additional `key:value` pair (`"x": "0"`) to make the JSON valid:

```
SELECT d.Id, j.*
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (
   CASE 
      WHEN d.Body IS NULL THEN '{}'
      ELSE CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), 'x": "0"}')
   END   
) WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
   Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
   Page_Load_Count int '$."Page load count"'
) j
```

**Update:**

The next lines of code may help, if you want to implement a trigger (I think you need a different kind of trigger).

Table and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE MailArchive (
   Id int,
   Mail_Body varchar(max),
   Status varchar(100),
   Successful_actions_count int,
   Page_load_count int
);
CREATE TRIGGER BodyParseTrigger ON MailArchive INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO MailArchive (ID, Mail_Body, Status, Successful_Actions_Count, Page_Load_Count)
   SELECT i.ID, i.Mail_Body, j.Status, j.Successful_Actions_Count, j.Page_Load_Count
   FROM Inserted i
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(i.Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
   WITH (
      Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
      Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
      Page_Load_Count int '$."Page load count"'
   ) j
END
```

Statement:

```
INSERT INTO MailArchive
   (Id, Mail_Body)
VALUES
   (1, 'Status: Completed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Successful actions count: 106' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Page load count: 105')

SELECT *
FROM MailArchive
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  Mail_Body                     Status      Successful_actions_count  Page_load_count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Status: Completed             Completed   106                         105
    Successful actions count: 106
    Page load count: 105
```

**How to remove additional line breaks:**

If your `Mail_Body` column holds additional line breaks, you may try to change the transformation to eliminate the possible JSON parsing error. Now, the result from transformation will be a JSON array (`["Status: Completed", ...]`), not a JSON object (`{"Status":"Completed", ...}`). In this case, you should use `OPENJSON()` with default schema (without the `WITH` clause) and use `MAX()` to get the expected results:

Table and data with additional line breaks:

```
DECLARE @text1 varchar(max) = 
   'Status: Completed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
   'Successful actions count: 106' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
   'Page load count: 105' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @text2 varchar(max) = 
   'Agent did not meet defined success criteria on this run.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   'Status: Completed' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
   'Successful actions count: 106' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
   'Page load count: 105' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int,
   Mail_Body varchar(max) 
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (Id, Mail_Body)
VALUES 
   (1, @text1),
   (2, @text2)
```

Statememnt:

```
SELECT d.Id, j.[Status], j.Successful_actions_count, j.Page_load_count
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT
      MAX(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Status:', [value]) = 1 THEN REPLACE([value], 'Status:', '') END) AS [Status],
      MAX(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Successful actions count:', [value]) = 1 THEN REPLACE([value], 'Successful actions count:', '') END) AS [Successful_actions_count],
      MAX(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Page load count:', [value]) = 1 THEN REPLACE([value], 'Page load count:', '') END) AS [Page_load_count]
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.Mail_Body, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"]'))
) j
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Id   Status      Successful_actions_count   Page_load_count
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    Completed   106                        105
2    Completed   106                        105
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when running your Statement: `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '}' is found at position 3.`  I did a little googling and stack overflowing, but not seeing how this appiles to what I'm running?

Comment: Zhorov, you are absolutely right.  So now I've tweaked the statement to operate on only one record as a test, which definitely has a value in `Body`- now I'm getting the same error but related to character "," at position 246.  Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: There are a couple additional lines in the `Body` field beyond what I have in my original post.  Is it necessary to add those to the `WITH` part of your statement?  I assumed your `WITH` statement will just handle the first 3 lines even if there is more in there.

Comment: Hmm, ok that's what I thought.  I will try to determine why I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Zhorov, should there be double quotes around the word "Status" in `'$.Status'`? That doesn't fix my issue, but noticed it as an inconsistency to the other two strings.

Comment: I figured out the error.  I like this solution a lot, it's spot on to what I asked for.  Marking it as the answer.

Comment: Zhorov, sorry I jumped the gun and marked this as answer too soon.  It works to DISPLAY what I need for existing records, but what I need is for this to actually WRITE the data to the fields for incoming records.  The problem is your `OPENJSON` solution doesn't work for Trigger purposes, thus the question isn't fully answered.

Comment: I am editing my post now to include additional data about the Trigger issues.  Please take a look and let me know if you can help.

Comment: Zhorov, this is great, and now it makes sense to me.  I think I'm really close.  I'm still getting an error about an JSON text not properly formatted (this time it says position 240 but I really don't even know what that means tbh).  I can see from your example though that it's clearly working for you.  The only difference for me is that there ARE a few more columns to be parsed from the `Body` than the 3 I'm showing but I left those out intentionally to abide by the minimal reproducible example rules around here. Let me go back and triple-check to see if it's just a syntax issue on my side.

Comment: I see the problem. Not sure of the solution.  The reason it's working for you is you're explicitly putting in `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` as part of the INSERT statement.  If I do that, it works.  But when I test the Trigger by sending a record to the database from the application (which is how it will always function), I get the JSON error.  So somehow, the value for `Body` on the incoming records must not be exactly formatted as what I'm showing in my original post, despite the fact I copied and pasted it exactly.

Comment: And once it's already in the database, then the `OPENJSON` function works against the `Body` field, which is why testing just that function against existing records shows me what I'd expect to see.  So it looks like I need to understand the exact format of the `Body` as it's coming into the database.

Comment: Or perhaps the solution is to do this AFTER the record has been inserted and treat it as an `UPDATE`.  Seems this would work as I know your `OPENJSON` statement works against `Body` value once it's in SQL Server.

Comment: Zhorov, one last effort to see if you can help before I go in another direction and leave you alone :)  Here is what the body of the email looks like when I pull it into Word and turn on hidden characters: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06413663589651414501 (ignore the misspelling of "Successfull") Given that info, do you think this changes the `CONCAT` statement?  I did try your `key:value` pair `("x": "0")` suggestion, but still received the same error.

Comment: Zhorov, this is really great, I'm learning a LOT from you, I'm very grateful.  Ok so I've determined that the JSON is not valid, as the ValidJSON field for incoming data is 0.  So now, how would I diagnose it to understand why?  Is there some further action I can take to see exactly WHY it's invalid?

Comment: Looks like there's definitely a carriage return at the end of the last line.  You're pretty confident that that additional key:value pair you presented is correct?  Is there a way in the `CONCAT` statement to ignore or "delete" that final carriage return?

Comment: I will test it now.  So the `SUBSTRING` statement goes at the end of the `CONCAT` statement but before the closing squiggly bracket, correct?

Comment: I'm getting error "Invalid column name 'x': when trying to create the trigger.  My `CONCAT` statement is `(CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(i.Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), SUBSTRING(x, 1, LEN(x) - 2), '"}'))`

Comment: Zhorov, let me know if you'd like to take this to a chat.  I'm also willing to pay you for your time in order to get this resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Zhorov, understood, and I appreciate it.  Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error with the new syntax you've provided.  This one is a beast!

Comment: Zhorov, I've opened a new thread specific to this `OPENJSON` error so we don't keep going to far off the original intent of this thread.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Stpete111 It's a real battle :). My final update, see `How to remove additional line breaks` part for another approach to transform the data as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Zhorov.  This latest one works!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than string_split() and a conditional aggregation AND the structure is consistant, there is another option... a little XML

**Example**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,Status  = stuff(Pos1,1,charindex(':',Pos1),'')
      ,Action  = try_convert(int,stuff(Pos2,1,charindex(':',Pos2),''))
      ,PageCnt = try_convert(int,stuff(Pos3,1,charindex(':',Pos3),''))
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(Body,char(13)+char(10),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID   Status     Action  PageCnt
1    Completed  106     105
```

Comment: Converting this to JSON would be easier and faster. Replace `:` with `':'` and newline with `','`, surround with `{` and `}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're missing a key step, i.e. quoting keys and values

Comment: Oops, not in the query I'm trying right now. The real pain is the end comma. It's still cleaner than XML but definitely not clean

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I can honestly say not only would I not have known to go down the route of XML - I didn't even know this functionality existed in SQL!  That's why S/O is so great!  So far, what you've presented works!  Let me test it against a sample population, make sure I understand what it's doing, and then I'll be back to mark this as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Stpete111  Always happy to help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The trailing comma could be as simple as +'"bogus":"bogus"}' Not sure I agree that it is cleaner, but it is still fun.  :)